# Accessing WASM functions from vanilla JS inside a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rust, webassembly

I am taking my first steps into using WebAssembly functions in JavaScript (inside React).

I know it's probably not the proper way to do this, but I've wrapped my entire app in the exported Rust functions, like this:

```js
import init from 'my-lib'

init().then((wasm) => {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App wasm={wasm} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  )
})
```

I then use a React Context to access the `wasm` object wherever I needed. It works fine. I've written a few Rust functions and replaced some of my code's heavy calculations with them. My CPU usage was cut in half, so of course I wanted to take it further.

My issue is with a non-React JS file that is used in the project. It runs a timer and exports some functions that allow React component to subscribe to different events (this allows me to have a single central timer for the entire application).

I have no idea how to import the WebAssembly functions into that file, because of course I can't use React Contexts there (and the `init().then` syntax doesn't work). How can I make the functions inside the vanilla JS file access the functions defined in the WASM package?

Comment: How are you constructing your `init()` function? It may be safe to call multiple times. If it isn't you should be able to cache the promise it returns and just `.then()` whenever you need the wasm value.

Comment: I am not constructing any `init()` function myself, to tell the truth I'm not even sure where it comes from. The only thing I managed to do was to export my Rust functions. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.tkat0.dev/posts/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-rust-and-wasm/). I finally imported the `wasm` code successfully at the top of my script with `import init from 'my-lib'; let wasm; init().then((res) => wasm = res)`. It works but doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `init` returns a promise you can just use that promise over and over to make sure you get access to the same return value.

```
import init from 'my-lib'

let wasmPromise = null;

export function getWasm(){
  if( !wasmPromise ){
    wasmPromise = init();
  }

  return wasmPromise;
}
```

You can then use it from wherever you want.

```
import { getWasm } from './my-wasm-wrapper'

getWasm().then( wasm => /* whatever */ )

getWasm().then( wasm => /* same wasm as above */ )
```